# How get the working location from Google Calendar?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

Do you know how get the working location from Google Calendar with Google Apps Script?

It's not an event but I don't see anything in the reference doc that could help me to get this information.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to set working location manually from Calendar UI, see https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/7638168#working_location

It is not possible to do programmatically (yet). See
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/199918380. Add a "star" to this feature request to let Google know you are interested, also it will enable notifications on this issue.

Comment: Thanks ! There's also this issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/198667127  , I add starts to both of them.

Comment: @Lucile don't forget to mark this answer as accepted if it answers your question.